# Glazed eyes vs. glassy eyes

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Do they mean the same? Example sentence:

> Her eyes were glazed. Was she about to cry?
>
> Her eyes were glassy. Was she about to cry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a first approximation, they mean the same. In fact, I would say the biggest difference is that *syntactically*, we're much more likely to use adjectival ***glassy-eyed*** and adverbial *[with] **glazed eyes***.

But *sometimes, some people* will distinguish ***glassy-eyed*** as more evocative of an *intoxicated* state or similar (drunk, drugged, in extreme shock), whereas ***glazed eyes*** tends rather to suggest ***inattentiveness** (through **boredom** or **lack of comprehension**)*.

> **glassy-eyed**
> *having eyes that are **void of expression**, life, or warmth, esp because of drugs or alcohol*

> **glazed**
> *If you describe someone's eyes as glazed, you mean that their expression is dull or dreamy, usually because they are tired or are having difficulty concentrating on something.*
> ...
> Synonyms: ***expressionless**, cold, fixed, empty*

(I've highlight "void of expression" and "expressionless" to reinforce my point that there's a *lot* of overlap.)

Comment: Excellent points. Great answer!